# How to edit Thirdweb ERC721 drop contract to set predetermined price within the contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, erc-721

I am trying to set a predetermined dynamic price based on tokenid for the minting or claiming of nfts within the contract, but utilizing the thirdweb sdk. For example, id#1 = $1, id#2 = $2, etc. etc.

However, thirdwebs erc721drop contract uses their interface to set the price as a claimcondition with their set claim phase functionality. I am new to solidity programming and am not experienced in programming in general and have been struggling to figure out what would be the best way to add this logic into the contract. I want to keep the alterations to a bare minimum to reduce the risk of breaking the contract or creating vulnerabilities.

I have currently boiled it down to the dropSinglePhase extension and I am assuming I would need to add my logic in somewhere within the setclaimconditions function. The function allows users to set new claim conditions and it seems to be the primary means of interacting with the pricePerToken variable. I think by default it is unclaimable until conditions are set using this function.

But I am still very unsure if it is possible/practical to add logic within this function, or if a new function should be made. Or if the logic can be inserted elsewhere and utilize an override function somehow. Additionally, I am also unsure of how I can access the current tokenid variable to calculate the price for the token.

The thirdweb contract has a lot of features and functionality, so as a noob to programming I am hesitant to add in my own functions and too much of my own logic. If there is anyone with experience using the thirdweb sdk and/or solidity smart contract development in general, I would appreciate some noob-level guidance on how I can go about adding the tokenid-based dynamic pricing within the erc721drop contract in the cleanest way possible.

Links to thirdwebs sdk code:

ERC721base: [ERC721 base contract code](https://portal.thirdweb.com/solidity/base-contracts/erc721base)

Dropsinglephase: [Drop Single Phase function code](https://portal.thirdweb.com/solidity/extensions/dropsinglephase#full-api-reference/?utm_source=dc)

I've also added the code for thirdwebs setClaimConditions function within the dropSinglePhase extension:

```
    /// @dev Lets a contract admin set claim conditions.
function setClaimConditions(ClaimCondition calldata _condition, bool _resetClaimEligibility) external override {
    if (!_canSetClaimConditions()) {
        revert("Not authorized");
    }

    bytes32 targetConditionId = conditionId;
    uint256 supplyClaimedAlready = claimCondition.supplyClaimed;

    if (_resetClaimEligibility) {
        supplyClaimedAlready = 0;
        targetConditionId = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_dropMsgSender(), block.number));
    }

    if (supplyClaimedAlready > _condition.maxClaimableSupply) {
        revert("max supply claimed");
    }

    claimCondition = ClaimCondition({
        startTimestamp: _condition.startTimestamp,
        maxClaimableSupply: _condition.maxClaimableSupply,
        supplyClaimed: supplyClaimedAlready,
        quantityLimitPerWallet: _condition.quantityLimitPerWallet,
        merkleRoot: _condition.merkleRoot,
        pricePerToken: _condition.pricePerToken,
        currency: _condition.currency,
        metadata: _condition.metadata
    });
    conditionId = targetConditionId;
    

    emit ClaimConditionUpdated(_condition, _resetClaimEligibility);
}
```

Thanks.